# Tensorflow terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error' what(): Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow

it seems that after loading a saved model and then opening a session, `tf.Session()`
will cause **terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'   what():  Resource temporarily unavailable**. 
but, using `tf.Session()` without loading a model works fine.
i was wondering is there a minimum a mount or RAM needed.
i'm working with ubuntu 16.04 server.
1GB RAM.
python 3.6.3 
tensorflow 1.4.1
trained model size 53MB.
the model has been tested locally and it's working perfectly.
does increasing the RAM will solve this problem??
 and if so what is the amount of RAM needed??